# Query error when use group by

Tags: apex, soql, query, group-by

can anyone explain it to me, why my query is error?
here my query :

```
        PYEMPELEMENT__c[] VFLDLSTEmpSeparated = [SELECT Employee_No__c, Period__c FROM PYEMPELEMENT__c GROUP BY Employee_No__c, Period__c LIMIT 1];
```

Comment: This is not a very well formed question. You should always include the ***verbatim error message*** when you encounter an error. Glad to see you got the problem solved but there is still room for improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change it

```
List<AggregateResult > VFLDLSTEmpSeparated = [SELECT Employee_No__c, Period__c FROM PYEMPELEMENT__c GROUP BY Employee_No__c, Period__c LIMIT 1];
```

When we use group by and other aggregate function we will get `List<AggregateResult >` so instead of sObject list we need to use this list and then we can parse the result

Comment: if i want to use VFLDLSTEmpSeparated.Employee_No__c in other method, how to store Employee_No__c field into variable? @TusharSharma

Comment: @Vikolai `VFLDLSTEmpSeparated[0].get('Employee_No__c')`

Answer (score 0):

You are right Tushar, we need AggregateResult List. 
And to fetch the values you can later cast the AggregateResult

```
Set<Integer> empNumber = new Set<Integer>();  
for (AggregateResult results : [SELECT Employee_No__c, Period__c FROM PYEMPELEMENT__c GROUP BY Employee_No__c, Period__c LIMIT 1]){
    empNumber.add((Integer)results.get('Employee_No__c'));
}
```